# jQuery event when hash tag (or any character) is typed!

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a textarea field on my website and I'd like to use jQuery to trigger an event when a user types the hash tag.  Similar to the trend of websites like Facebook and Twitter who allow you to query a database for friends as you type after you type a hash tag or use the '@' symbol.

Would anyone be able to provide a plugin or example of how I could get started in the right direction with this?  I've looked at the autocomplete plugin, which works great for querying the database, but what if I wanted to do something else, like pop up a div, etc?  I'm basically looking for a way to trigger an even when the hash tag is typed and close the event when a user keeps typing?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [keydown](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/), [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) or [keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) events (depending on your use case), and then check what character was last typed in the textarea in the handler. If the character is # - do a specific thing. Take a look at the examples on those documentation pages, and `event.keyCode`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/01/jquery-acting-on-specific-key-events/

or a Javascript jQuery plugin for hooking keyboard events:
http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/